# How to use rails routes in grape entities?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, grape-entity

I have an image entity exposes a url to a rails controller.

The controller shows the image conforming to some business logic. (ex it deletes the image if everybody in the group viewed it,...)

```
  expose :media_url do |message, options|
    #TODO inject the rails route helper
  end
```

How could I inject the rails named route helper into the code above?

Any other hint is also welcome :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This helped

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.message_image_url message.id
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

https://github.com/intridea/grape/wiki/Grape-and-Rails-Path-Helpers

<del># Include rails helpers 
    include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

    expose :media_url do |message, options|
       # Something like
       asset_url(message.media_url)
    end</del>

Comment: asset_path was unknown in that context.

Comment: Ye, sorry that doesn't work which is a shame, but following the advice on the link should.